# Begleiter notwendig bzw. nicht notwendig

Tags: usage, genitive

Folgender Satz ist richtig:

> Er sucht Vaters Pfeife.

Deshalb würde man davon ausgehen, dass auch der folgende Satz richtig ist:

> Er sucht Sohnes Schaukelpferd.

Nun weiß ich allerdings, dass der zweite Beispielsatz falsch ist. Richtig wäre:

> Er sucht das Schaukelpferd des Sohnes.

**Frage**:
Weshalb kann man das Nomen *Sohn* in obigem Beispiel nicht auf die gleiche Weise verwenden, wie das Nomen *Vater*?
Und falls es dafür keine Regel gibt, wäre ich auf der Suche nach einer möglichst vollständigen Liste mit Nomen, die sich ebenso verhalten wie die Nomen *Vater, Grossvater, Mutter, Gott*. Es fällt mir gerade auf, dass es sich vielleicht um Verwandtschaftsnomen handeln könnte. Allerdings: Bei *Sohn, Tochter, Cousin* ist eine Satzkonstruktion gemäss Beispiel 1 ja auch wieder falsch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich finde den zweiten Satz nicht unbedingt falsch. Der Unterschied ist, dass *Vater*, im Gegensatz zu *Sohn*, vielfach als Anrede (im Sinne eines Eigennamen) verwendet wird.

Wenn man als sagt *Er sucht Vaters Pfeife*, dann würde das bedeuten, dass jemand, der die Person üblicherweise als *Vater* anredet, diesen Satz sagt. Ebenfalls kann es sein, dass derjenige, der den Satz sagt, diesen zu jemandem sagt, der die Person üblicherweise als *Vater* anredet.

Wäre es eine "familienfremde" Person, würde sie sagen

> Er sucht des/seines Vaters Pfeife.

Noch deutlicher wird das beispielsweise mit *Papa*. Die Mutter oder irgendein anderes Familienmitglied könnte sagen:

> Marie sucht Papas Pfeife.

Eine fremde Person würde aber sagen:

> Marie sucht des/ihres Papas Pfeife.

---

Und weil Du beispielsweise auch *Gott* anführst, hier gilt das Gleiche: *Gott* kann zum einen abstrakt als besondere Bezeichnung *einer Gottheit* gesehen werden, oder aber als Anrede/Bezeichnung der speziellen Gottheit einer Religionsgemeinschaft.

Im ersten Fall würde man beispielsweise als Nicht-Angehöriger der Religionsgemeinschaft (oder wenn man nicht in seiner Eigenschaft als Angehöriger über diese Gemeinschaft spricht) sagen:

> Christen, Moslems, Naturvölker - alle glauben an einen eigenen Gott.

Spricht man als Christ/Moslem/etc. über "seinen" Gott, dann sagt man aber:

> Ich habe Gott gefunden. (Nicht: ich habe *den* Gott gefunden)

---

Beispiel aus meinem Umfeld: Ein Bekannter spricht, wenn er über seine 3 Söhne spricht, gerne über "Sohn Nr. Eins", "Sohn Nr. Zwei" und "Sohn Nr. Drei". Er sagt dann also Dinge wie:

> Wir haben den ganzen Tag Sohn Nr. Eins' Handy gesucht.

---

Wenn Du mal die alte Zeichentrickserie "Heidi" anschaust, wirst Du sehen, dass Heidi ihren Großvater auch wirklich als *Großvater* anspricht:

> Aber Großvater...

Würde sie dem Geißen-Peter etwas über ihren Großvater erzählen, könnte sie sagen:

> Wir waren in Großvaters Stube ...

anstatt

> Wir waren in des Großvaters Stube ...

weil *Großvater* aus ihrer Sicht ein normaler "Eigenname" ist.

Comment: Ein weiteres Beispiel, dass diene Antwort unterstützt: *Er fährt mit Peters Fahrrad.* Aber nicht: *Er fährt mit Freunds Fahrrad.* Sondern: *Er fährt mit dem Fahrrad seines Freundes.*

Comment: Das mit der Anrede, das kommt nicht ganz hin. Die Mutter kann auch zur Tochter sagen, dass sie Vaters/Papas Pfeife sucht, obwohl sie ihren Mann (angenommen ihr Mann ist der Tochter Vater) nicht mit Vater oder Papa anredet.

Comment: Deshalb schrieb ich auch, dass es ebenfalls sein kann, dass man sowas zu jemandem sagt, der die andere Person entsprechend anredet, eben genau wie dein Beispiel.